# JS Context (?) process

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, javascript-objects

I have a js variable like that:

```
var commands = {
    hello: {
        command: "hello",
        action: "say hello"
    },
    open_paint: {
        command: "open paint",
        action: "open paint"
    }
};
```

Is this a Context?

Is there a way to process everything inside the variable "command" so I can process every command and every action?

I don't know if you can understand.

Please tell me something, I can try to explain better.

Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't really look like "context", whatever that is? It is however an object.

Answer (score 1):

You can just loop through your commands like this :

```
for(i in commands) {
    // Here, you can do something with commands[i].command or commands[i].action;
    // For example :
    console.log(commands[i].action);

    for(j in commands[i]) {
        // Here, you can do something with commands[i][j];
        // For example :
        console.log(commands[i][j]);
    }
}
```

See also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/kzuhovkb/1/).

Comment: Instead of the 2nd loop, I'd just use `commands[i].command` or `commands[i].action`

Comment: @RocketHazmat : I'd realized that possibility as well. See my updated answer ;-)

Comment: thank you very much. I've tried a normal for loop and obviously commands.length hasn't worked. Thanks